# Como resolver critica do SONARqube: Read of unwritten field connector

Tags: java, sonarqube

Em minha classe no método findRecursosMensagem() o SONARqube faz uma crítica, mas não entendi o que deve ser corrigido. Poderiam me ajudar a entender o que deve ser feito?

```
public class LoginController extends AbstractController  implements AuthenticationProvider, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private Connector connector;    
    @Resource(name = "messageSource")
    protected MessageSource messageSource;
    
    @Inject
    private IntegracaoService integracaoService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index() {
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logar", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Autenticacao logar(@RequestBody AutenticacaoDMN autenticacao, HttpServletRequest request){
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        autenticacao.setSistema(SISTEMA);
        Autenticacao autenticacaoRetorno = integracaoService.login(autenticacao);
        if (autenticacaoRetorno.isAutenticado()) {
            autenticacao.setIdUsuario(autenticacaoRetorno.getIdUsuario());
            integracaoService.setUserAutenticate(autenticacao, request);
        }
        
        return autenticacaoRetorno;
    }   

    private List<Map<String, Object>>  findRecursosMensagem(){
        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
        args.put("chave", "MensagemCovid");
        List<Map<String, Object>> mensagem = null;
        mensagem = connector.findServicoReturnList(args, "lms.radar.usuarioFacade.findRecursosMensagem");
        return mensagem;        
    }
}
```

[image: mensagem/crítica do SONARqube]

Comment: Sonar tem sempre uma explicação. Clica ali no `See Rule`, que ele te explica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem um `code smell` em:

```
mensagem = connector.findServicoReturnList(args, "lms.radar.usuarioFacade.findRecursosMensagem");
return mensagem;
```

Só retornar direto sem atribuir para a variável mensagem. Ficaria assim:

```
return connector.findServicoReturnList(args, "lms.radar.usuarioFacade.findRecursosMensagem");
```

Sobre o erro crítico do sonar, na variável `connector`, como ela está sendo instanciada?
Porque não tem construtor pra injetar, não tem @Autowired.
De fato, o Sonar está sinalizando que ela pode ser nula no momento da execução do código abaixo:

```
connector.findServicoReturnList(args, "lms.radar.usuarioFacade.findRecursosMensagem");
```

Answer (score 0):

O que a ferramenta tá dizendo é que o objeto `connector` não foi inicializado, e tu estás lendo/acessando/chamando um método dele.

Isso pode ser tanto um falso-positivo (algumas vezes - principalmente em versões mais antigas do sonar, a ferramenta não detecta inicializações feitas "indiretamente" - como as que são feitas pelo Spring, quando tu usas um `@autowired`, por exemplo) quanto um problema grave que pode causar um erro de runtime (um NullPointerException, por exemplo) se passar pela linha de código.

Se, no teu caso, for um falso positivo, tu precisas ajustar as regras do Sonar para que isso não seja pego como um problema.